# Embed HTML browser into a native C++/Win32 project using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, browser, embed

I have a C++ project in the MS Visual Studio 2008 IDE (note, NO MFC, NO .NET, just native Win32 APIs!) and I was wondering if it is possible to add to it a child window that can parse and render HTML/CSS/JavaScript, like a browser. It would be very good if that window did not have browser controls/buttons/borders -- if it just rendered HTML.

Is it a tall order to ask for such?

Comment: Try Webkit. if you don't want to write a framework around it alone, try Qt.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but the web-kit doesn't seem to "play well" with Visual Studio (to my knowledge)...

Comment: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could embed an HTLM Browser (Internet Explorer) within your windows with some heavy use of COM. I used to do that and have the same need to avoid MFC, .NET, etc. This control is quite configurable, and you can remove and/or override pretty much anything.

I did my work based on an old article in The Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cwebpage.aspx

Comment: Awesome! Let me look through it. I'm also assuming that by IE you mean whatever the lastest version is installed, like 9 at the current stage of events, right?

Comment: @ahmd0: Indeed, IE is whatever the latest version is installed. Just as its done by Microsoft itself with Explorer, MSN, etc.

Comment: The web browser control is NOT the latest IE installed, you need to configure a registy key with your executable.