# How to Open web page over win32 c++ app

Tags: c++, winapi

I am pretty new to **Win32 c++** programming, and I have been trying to do the following with my limited skills..

I am trying to open **web page over win32 window in c++**, I have found a solution with following command :

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, L"http://www.google.com", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );
```

But it's not a usefull becouse it works on inbuilt browser(Chrome), I have a code where i show a simple **"Hello world!"** over the window ,

```
// GT_HelloWorldWin32.cpp
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Win32 Guided Tour Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, World!");

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, World!"
        // in the top left corner.
        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));

        // End application-specific layout section.

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But My requirement is to open web page over own app window at the place of Hello world!

[image]

if anyone have a sol plz share

Thanksss!!!

Comment: Do you want to program a web browser?

Comment: @Axalo: I just want to render web page over window where i show the hello world

Comment: I think you need to use some `ActiveX` controls.

Comment: There is an [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx) in MFC, may be you can get some help from this.

Comment: You can use WinHTTP API to receive the code of the page from the requested server. Rendering the page is a diferent task. Either you write the code yourself (meaning you have to process the HTML code by yourself) or you look for a free HTML display control (ActiveX?) on the internet.

Comment: @Himanshu: can u show me the sample of  control  ActiveX how can i use it

Comment: Not an answer, but if you already want to do such fancy things while you're at the beginning of learning win32(/c/c++), you might really like [Qt](http://qt-project.org). It is much easier than trying to figure out win32. In your case, if you already have the window, all you need to display a webpage in it is 1 single line of code with Qt.

Comment: @SanjeevSangral, i given one link in my last comment. [Check this link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4379/Display-a-Web-Page-in-a-Plain-C-Win32-Application.htm) also. one more is [there](https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=115)

Comment: @Himanshu: i got it from "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18417/Use-an-ActiveX-control-in-your-Win-Project-witho" thks man for a trick ActiveX

Comment: @SanjeevSangral, your welcome. Statckoverflow having one solution [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681420/embed-html-browser-into-a-native-c-win32-project-using-visual-studio)

Comment: @Himanshu: thanku so much

Answer (score 0):

It is rather complicated. There are article that show how to , [Embed HTML browser into a native C++/Win32 project using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681420/embed-html-browser-into-a-native-c-win32-project-using-visual-studio)

and here http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4379/Display-a-Web-Page-in-a-Plain-C-Win32-Application.htm